# SSIS - Performing Lookup on MS Access datatypes Long Text (NTEXT) and Doubles (DT_R8)

Tags: ms-access, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have an MS Access table that is currently holding several tables with columns that have Long Text (that are set as NTEXT in SSIS) and Doubles (that are set as DT_R8). Data migration (Update and Insert) between this Access DB and a SQL Server DB will be occurring a number of times for the next year or so, and so I'm trying to write an SSIS package in order to perform the data migration and I'm having difficulties with those data types.

This is the process I want to perform: 
OLE DB Source (MS Access) -> Lookup -> (other dataflow actions) -> OLE DB Destination (SQL)

However, when I try to perform the Lookup, I'm getting the BLOB error and Float error (understandably). I've tried OLE DB Source (MS Access) -> Data conversion -> Lookup -> OLE DB Destination (SQL), but the Lookup always references the OLE DB Source data (with the NTEXT and DT_R8 datatypes). I've tried CAST and CONVERT, but those also bring up various different errors in their own right. So I'm not exactly sure what to do now.

Any guidance or ideas would be welcomed.

Comment: Try to create a table with the Access data and let SSIS configure the data types, run it to see if it works and then analyze it.

Comment: Columns with the Long Text have been converted to nvarchar(MAX) and those with Double (Number) have been converted to float. Forgive me for asking, but how will that help with the repeated data migration? I already know that the data will be converted just fine. It's the process of updating and inserting new rows based on the Access DB into SQL in between the Source and the Destination that is confusing me.

Comment: You can create a temp table with the Access Data and then use the Lookup tool.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The lookup finally runs now. Thank you!